# Find me in a code (and be faster than Bob)

Tags: story, cipher

On a day when Bob chose to meet his friend, Alice, at her house, Alice decided to go a trip! Picking up his phone, Bob tried calling Alice, but no one answered. As Bob turned to leave the front door, he saw a note on a **piece** of paper on the second step down.

Here's what the note said:

> IG2CPV2ASF2SFAEINJ2UHIT2CPOOA2I2XFNU2TPOFXHFSF2GINE2OF2IN2GCEEFE2CIEEECI2FFFFFFFF2HHHHEFG2GGCGBC2FFCCIC2ECBB         Remember G.N.

Bob ran home, deciphered the message, packed his bags, hailed a cab and headed to a transportation place (if I tell you this, it might give extra hints to the answer), all in 2 hours.

**Where was Bob going to?**

Hints

> One character acts as a separator.

According to @Deusovi's recommendations, I have added a place to start this puzzle with...

> Where do you see the **note**?

Comment: Your code looks *very* similar to the one in [Code Puzzles: What not to do?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do) on meta. Please read that before creating any more ciphers,

Comment: Do you mean the code "fw8904730983kf89023ncweamnfiope20tmi9b6m89ny327nery895mbi9tm0ei09x2e1m3y8n2"? (the one on the meta)

Comment: Yes: long sttrings like that are heavily discouraged here.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm kind of new here at PSE.

Comment: This isn't really an issue with PSE, but with puzzles as a whole. When you design a puzzle, you are setting up a battle of wits. You've got that part down. But it's not just *any* battle of wits: it's a battle of wits that *you, the creator, set yourself up to lose*. A puzzle that doesn't have that - a puzzle where the maker wins  - simply isn't *fun*. Imagine going into the final boss of a video game and getting destroyed within seconds unless you flipped your controller upside down and entered a 20-button code. That's what these codes feel like: you 'win' not by a logical path but by...

Comment: ...trying things until something happens to work.

Comment: So...should I add something so that those who try to figure out this code have a place to begin?

Comment: @mestackoverflow I think the imporant thing is to add something, which makes it *fun* to work at your puzzle, otherwise, why should one bother? I think, that is what Deusovi also tried to say.

Comment: @Deusovi That is probably one of the best metaphors for puzzle-creation I've heard, and I think it warrants its own answer on the meta question.

Comment: @2012rcampion Thank you! o: I'm not really sure how I could elaborate on that enough to make it an actual answer, but I could post it if you think it would be okay.

Comment: Why did Bob run home? Wasn't he already home?

Comment: Wait... No, but then why was he on his phone at her house?

Comment: Bob was on the phone at Alice's house because no one answered the door at the house, then he found the note at Alice's house. So Bob ran home to decipher the message and pack up to find Alice.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the beginning is "IG2ZPV..." I think I can decode half of the message but it partly depends on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I'm sort of on the right track so I'm going to take a shot at it and say the answer is

> China

Deciphering the first part of the note.

> Considering the following decryption method: 
>  (i) Let each of the letters in the word 'CHINA' be an alphabet fixed point, i.e, each of those letters maps to itself in the decryption 
>  (ii) For each letter that is not a fixed point, map it to the previous letter in the alphabet that is not a fixed point. So, Z $\rightarrow$ Y, P $\rightarrow$ O but D $\rightarrow$ B as C is a fixed point and B $\rightarrow$ Z as A is a fixed point. Most importantly, note that J $\rightarrow$ G (**NB** "step down") 
>  (iii) The number 2 acts as a separator and can be mapped to a space character. 
>  With this convention the decrypted note reads 
>  IF (C)OU ARE READING THIS COMMA I WENT SOMEWHERE FIND ME IN FCDDED CIDDDCI EEEEEEEE HHHHDEF FFCFZC EECCIC DCZZ 
>  Now, the second part of this message is still undeciphered using the 'China' method and it's quite possible that we don't use it on this part of the puzzle, so it possibly should be left as is with 2 still replacing the space character.

Remember G.N.

> I think the second half of the note must refer to some musical phrase perhaps referencing a song giving Alice's location (most of it is from the start of the alphabet with additional characters perhaps represting flats and sharps). The purposeful emboldening of **note** and **piece** also suggest a musical connection. 
>  As far as musicians with the initials G.N. go, one that springs to mind is **G**ary **N**uman who happens to have a song entitled "Slow Car to China". It's possible that the transportation place that Bob has headed to is a garage housing "slow cars" and such a revelation would be a dead giveaway for this puzzle, as suggested by the asker. I reckon that the second part of the note turns out to be a musical phrase from a song such as this (with a title containing the name of a place) although I don't know of an efficient way of working this out.

Note

> Obviously, the note does not decipher perfectly. The beginning is "IF COU" instead of "IF YOU" which is where my comment comes from. I have not yet had an answer from the asker to confirm or deny that there is a typo. If somebody has another suggestion, please do share.

Comment: "Second step down" sounds like moving down a musical scale.  From where though? G.N. could indicate G natural, meaning second step down is Eb.

Comment: The place is correct! You are also correct about the musical connection, but G.N. is a different thing/person/something else.

Comment: I am not sure if the "COU" part was a typo, but if it wasn't, it wouldn't have been any clue.